# Show precompactness for not necessarily continuous functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

I know that for showing precompactness of subsets of continuous functions, Arzelà-Ascoli is the tool of choice. However, the setting I'm facing here are functions in $L^1$.

**More precisely:**

> Let
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> E_1 &= \{ f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:\,f(x) = x^{-\alpha},\,0\leq\alpha < 1\}\\
> E_2 &= \{ f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:\,f(x)=x^{-\alpha},\,-\infty < \alpha\leq 1-\delta\}\text{ with fixed } \delta > 0\\
> E_3 &= \{ f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}:\,f(x) = \sin(\omega x),\,\omega\in\mathbb{R}\}
> \end{align}
> $$
>   Show whether those sets are bounded and/or precompact as subsets of $L^1((0,1))$.

Boundedness is clear, we can just calculate the anti-derivative for functions from $E_1$ and $E_2$ and see that they need to be bounded for functions from $E_2$ but not for functions from $E_1$.

For $E_3$ just estimate $\sin(x) \leq 1$ and you see that $E_3$ is also bounded.

**Now how to show precompactness?** I need to show that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite covering of $E_1,E_2,E_3$ using $\varepsilon$-balls (or not).

In my opinion we need to somehow select a finite family of functions from $E_i$, say $f^i_1,\dots,f^i_k$ s.t. all $f^i\in E_i$ belong to some ball $$B(f_j^i,\varepsilon) =  \{g\in E_i:\, \|f_j^i - g\|_{L^1} < \varepsilon\}$$

I don't understand how to choose such a set. My intuition for this is: $$\text{bounded} \Leftrightarrow \text{Precompact}$$ which is obviously wrong.

Maybe someone can show me how to start this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since $E_1$ is not bounded,  it can not be (pre)compact.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  But how can I start with the other ones?